# Running rails project on another machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a website on rails. I tried to move my project on another machine and start the rails server but the server doesn't start. Instead when I enter the command rails s in terminal it creates various files. Please let me know the steps I should follow to run my project on another machine. I have rails installed there.

Comment: have you migrated the DB? Are both computers using the same version of ruby? please add as much information as you can, otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: The versions are same.But I didnt try migrating the DB. I ll try that. THnx

Comment: What version of Rails? rails -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like the other machine has rails 2 (instead of 3) installed, where running `rails <something>` would generate a new rails app called <something>